# how to insert data with variables in arangodb with python-arango

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql, python-arango

I try to insert data from a variable and can't find a way to do this, can someone help me? something like this:

```py
name = "mark"
surname = "clark"

db.collection('user').insert([{'username': @name, 'usersurname': @surname}])
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "db.collection.insert" function is intended to work with objects/arrays, and does not support "variables" as such.  In this case, you would use some sort of loop:

```py
list_of_persons = [ {name: 'mark', surname: 'clark'} ]
for p in list_of_persons:
    db.collection('user').insert({'username': p.name, 'usersurname': p.surname})
```

Since variables are an [AQL](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals.html) construct, they only supported in the [query](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/aql-query.html#explain-an-aql-query)/[cursor](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/aql-query-cursor-query-results.html) interface.  Here you can specify the variable in the AQL (like `@myVar`) and specify a "[bind variable](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-bind-parameters.html)" in the body of the call.  You will have to read the docs for specific implementation, as they all differ slightly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to study the documentation better but I'm starting out and the desire to try is too much. however I get this error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing". I read that it may be a loop problem but I don't understand which ... any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a Python problem, not specifically related to ArangoDB.  Make sure the line-endings in your file are correct (CRLF on Win, LF on *nix, CR on Mac) or the Python interpreter may throw an EOF.  Also, try taking out any "do it" logic (e.g insert/query/update/etc.) and just have it parse basic constructs and loops first.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `@name` and `@surname` is correct. What is missing is a call to a `bind_vars` dictionary in the AQL method. This will map the @ variables to their python variable values.

Here is your code using an alternative syntax. You will notice that I took the liberty to declare a `collection` variable as well; why not?

```
name = "mark"
surname = "clark"
collection = "user"

bind = {"@collection": collection, "name": name, "surname": surname}
aql = "INSERT {username: @name, usersurname: @surname} INTO @@collection"
query = db.aql.execute(aql, bind_vars=bind)
```

Note the single @ in front of variable names, but @@ in front of a collection name. In the `bind` dictionary, 0 and 1 @, respectively.